# How to create a given number of turtles based on a distance criterion

Tags: netlogo

We're creating code and we're having trouble doing the following:

We would like to create a specific number of turtles (for example 100 turtles)  based on the following criteria:

1. distance between agents must be greater than or equal to 2

We've already tried:

```
to setup    
ask n-of 100 patches [
        if not any? turtles in-radius 2 [      
    sprout-turtles 1 [ setup-turtles ] ]
        ]
      ]
end

to setup-turtles
set energy 0
set size 1
set color orange
end
```

it didn't work, because less than 100 agents are being born even though the world holds the required amount of agents, which in this case is 100

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you outline is running into issues because you are asking patches to sprout turtles if they meet some condition. Because the patches are operating in a random sequential order, you are selecting some patches that, by the time it is their turn to act, no longer fulfill the condition to `sprout` since other nearby patches have already sprouted a nearby turtle.

One option is to use a `while` loop to keep trying to sprout turtles until the desired number is reached:

```
to setup
  ca
  while [ count turtles < 100 ] [
    ask one-of patches with [ not any? turtles in-radius 2 ] [
      sprout 1    
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

**Be careful** with while loops- if you do not code such that the `while` condition can eventually become false, your model will run forever stuck in the loop.

Another option that will give a more explicit error if it fails would be to just create your number of turtles, then have them move to a space that fulfills the condition:

```
to setup-2
  ca
  crt 100 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles in-radius 2 ] 
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```